# How to check if JWT Token is valid on client side

Tags: asp.net-web-api, jwt, blazor-server-side, bearer-token

So basically my Blazor server app does a request to the Web Api that handles the login and returns the User with the access Token.

After that I store the token in session storage or cookies for future usings and to redirect the user on the profile page with login succesfull.

My question is: **How do I know that the returned Token is valid?**

If someone adds a random Token to the cookies then my app automatically thinks that he is logged in and shows the profile page right? (future web-api calls should not work becouse the token is invalid corect?)

How can I avoid this?
Or what I'm doing wrong here?

Every help is apreciated.

Comment: Your running blazor server,  every page is rendered on the server, you can easily test the token is valid by calling an enpoint with the authorize attribute, why do you need to store the token, are you using client side JS ?

Comment: @fuzzybear As you may understood I'm not an expert of theese type of auth and seeing various videos I saw that everyone was storing the token in sessionstorage, localstorage or cookies and using it for allowing user tu access or not some pages and I did the same but I was not really sure if it was the right choice...